# In angular2 cli, I have imported base.js into component. I want to require base.js into child.js

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular2 cli, I have used a js class and imported it into a component. I want to import / require the base class from baseclass.js into Child class in child.js. In Child.js, i want to extend / inherit the base class

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create component And Load base.js file and child.js file using This code.

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-jquerydata',
     templateUrl: './jquerydata.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./jquerydata.component.css']
   })
   export class JquerydataComponent implements OnInit {


    public loadScript(url) {
       console.log('preparing to load...')
       let node = document.createElement('script');
       node.src = url;
       node.type = 'text/javascript';
       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }


     constructor(private elmref:ElementRef) { }

     ngOnInit():any {
       this.loadScript('assets/base.js');
       this.loadScript('assets/child.js');



     }

   }
   ```
2. Create base.js file

   ```
   function parent(){
   alert("parent");
   }
   ```
3. Create child.js file 
   we can call to parent() in perent.js file, inside child() in child.js file

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){

   child();

   })

    function child(){
     parent();
     alert("child");
   }
   ```